# How to convert file format of massive image

Tags: terminal, finder, preview, file-conversion

How can I convert a very large Portable Pixel Map ([`ppm`](http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/NETPBM/doc/ppm.html)) file into a `png` on MacOS?

I have a massive `ppm` image on my computer. The file is ~70 GB and I need to convert it to a png which would make it ~100 MB. I have cleared up enough space (>70 GB) on my machine to complete the conversion but am having some issues.

### What I Have Tried

1. Open image in preview and export to png

   Preview refuses to show the image and instead just shows a black square. When I try to export it tells me that the exported file will be zero bytes. So... no dice.
2. Use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) to convert the file from terminal

   This actually runs and tries to convert the file, but problems arise after about a minute of computation. First, my computer freezes then after a minute or two restarts because of a kernel panic.

Comment: I suggest you need more than 3 times the  70GB to get this to even think of working, there will be at least one temporary file produced during the process. I make sure to have 50% Free space on my drives...

Comment: I get the kernel panic with 30 GB of free storage still left on my machine.

Comment: 3 * 70 is 210GB... So 30GB is **way** too small. Think about it, you are trying to store 15 gallons of fuel in a 7 pint container. Get an external drive and archive some stuff.

Comment: Sorry I didn't word that well. I start off with about 71 GB of free storage. I then check how much storage was left as it was processing. It trickled down to 30 GB by the time I got the kernel panic. That means that it had only used up 40 GB. Shouldn't it have used up all 71 GB of storage on my computer before restarting?

Comment: It depends on what's happening in the background and how much space ImageMagick tries to allocate at once. It shouldn't kernel panic though (not having enough disk space is still an appliation issue if 30 GB are free) so there might be several problems in parallel here. Is the ppm something you can share (in a zipped version)?

Comment: Yes, I managed to zip the image bringing the size down to 140 MB, but how would I turn this into a png?

Comment: If the `netpbm` solution mentioned below doesn't work, can you put the ZIP into a publicly accessible place and share the link? I have more than enough diskspace, could verify the disk space theory.

Comment: Here is the zipped ppm file if you would like to test the theory: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xy7sZjL2CXG9IZerGWh12qk1xRqVOjoT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just an FYI.. I used [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org) to convert your file without any issue and have uploaded if you'd like it [mandelbrot.png.zip](https://gofile.io/d/zIB4sD) and will be available until Wed Mar 03 2021.  BTW I have over 500 GB free space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## netpbm

> Netpbm is a package of graphics programs and a programming library.

Try using the open source [netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net) tools to perform the conversion. The conversion will likely look like:

```
 pnmtopng input.ppm > output.png
```

Where `input.ppm` is the name of the existing large file and `output.png` is the name of the desired `png` formatted file.

The project talks about trying to [keep memory use low](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/#memoryusage):

> #### Memory Usage
>
> An important characteristic that varies among graphics software is how much memory it uses, and how. Does it read an entire image into memory, work on it there, then write it out all at once? Does it read one and write one pixel at a time? In Netpbm, it differs from one program to the next, but there are some generalizations we can make.
>
> Most Netpbm programs keep one row of pixels at a time in memory. Such a program reads a row from an input file, processes it, then writes a row to an output file. Some programs execute algorithms that can't work like that, so they keep a small window of rows in memory. Others must keep the entire image in memory. If you think of what job the program does, you can probably guess which one it does.

### Installing

You can install [netpbm](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/netpbm#default) on your Mac using the Homebrew project, see [Install Homebrew](https://brew.sh). Once `brew` is on your Mac, use the following command to install `netpbm`:

```
brew install netpbm
```

If you need help using the command line or tools mentioned, please [ask questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).